# Imprimir una palabra por cierto tiempo en python

Tags: python, print

¿Cómo puedo imprimir una palabra por cierto tiempo?

Como por ejemplo imprimir "Hola mundo" sería así:

```
print("Hola mundo")
```

Que tendría que agregar luego de eso para que se muestre por 5 segundos

Answer (score 2):

Si usas una terminal que soporta la secuencia de ANSI Escape podrías mover el cursor a la línea anterior, y de esta manera lo próximo que escribas sobrescribirá al mensaje que tiene que desaparecer. No encuentro que exista otra manera.

```
import time

print("Hola Mundo")
time.sleep(5)
print("\033[2A")
```

Aunque podrías simulando haciendo el proceso dos veces, la segunda agregando espacios en blancos según la cantidad de dígitos del mensaje:

```
import time

msg = "Hola Mundo"
print(msg)
time.sleep(5)
print("\033[2A")

#Y ahora sobrescribimos con espacios para eliminar el texto
print(" "*len(msg))
print("\033[2A")        #Subimos a la línea anterior de nuevo

#print("Nuevo mensaje si se requiere")
```

En cuanto a qué terminales lo soportan... Lo he comprobado con cmd, powershell y también debería funcionar con las de UNIX.
[Mas info sobre ANSI Escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php)

Comment: Otra opción es usar `\r` en vez de `\n`. Eso causa el retroceso al inicio de la línea actual, de modo que `print("Hola", end="\r")` deja todo listo para que al imprimir 5 segundos después `print("    ")` se tape el mensaje con espacios.